# What SMD components from an LCD control board are these?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, inductor, surface-mount

The reference designator of the first unknown component I'm asking for is "AC1". And then I can't find anything similar to the 10 µH pictured below too. It's around 1.2mm tall and has a floor around 5 mm x 6.2 mm. Both components are from an LCD control board.

Photos of the "AC1" component: [image: AC1 component photo]

Photos of the inductor:
[image: Inductor 10uH]

Thanks.

Comment: The inductor is just a low-profile inductor. I believe Coilcraft and Abracon both make similar--though not exactly the same--parts; I'm not sure who this is from though. It's very flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is an MLCC capacitor array.

Second one is an SMT inductor, looks like an unshielded type.

Comment: After disassembling it I can tell you that the inductor is semi-shielded. The winding is covered with magnetic-silica coating. Thanks.